# Monte Carlo simulation with SABR model

Tags: monte-carlo, sabr, sabr-model

I have to price European Options using only the classical **Monte Carlo** method.
The models I have to select are Lévy models and **SABR**. Consider for instance the simplest Lévy model: a Geometric Brownian Motion.

**My question is**: How does pricing a European Option via Monte Carlo method differ when employing a Lévy model versus a SABR model? Are distinct inputs required for each model, or do the underlying parameters remain consistent across both models?

P.S. Suppose that the spot is $S_0=€100$, the option is At-The-Money, the risk-free rate is $r=0.05$, the maturity is $T=1$ year.